# CSS optimize, extract common part?

Tags: css

for the following css style:

```
#div a {color:red}
#div li {width:100px}
#div span {font-size:10px}
```

is there any way to write the rules above to

```
#div{
a {color:red}
li {width:100px}
span {font-size:10px}
}
```

so just need to write #div once and easy to remove or modular different area of the webpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible right now with CSS (browsers do not support thet kind of syntex), yet as a developer it is possible using **[LESS](http://lesscss.org/)** or **[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)** (they are the most common).

LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operations and functions.

SASS is an extension of CSS3, adding nested rules, variables, mixins, selector inheritance, and more. It’s translated to well-formatted, standard CSS using the command line tool or a web-framework plugin.

You can also compare the two **[right here](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/)**.

Answer (score 1):

have you heard about "less" (http://lesscss.org/) this could do such things for you.

in less your style-code is exactly you wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do it with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do so, but not with pure css. As an alternative, you could use those:

- [LESS](http://www.lesscss.org)
- [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

There's more of those supersets around on the web, but LESS and Sass are probably the most common.

The syntax is nested in just the way you asked for and is compatible with native css.